# update mysql table encode special characters

Tags: php, mysql, autocomplete, special-characters, encode

I have a mysql table called "Movies". I just found that some movies contains special characters. For example, there are some movies that I crawled and inserted in my table such as 'WALL·E' or 'Mr. and Mrs. Smith', but they are inserted in DB as 'WALL & middot ; E' and 'Mr. & amp ; Mrs. Smith'. This caused a problem in my survey application, because for example I have an autocompletion field in my survey where user should insert his/her favorite movie name, so if user try to find WALL·E, he has to insert 'WALL & middot ; E'!!

Is there any way (preferably in mysql) that I can update my table and replace all movies that contains special characters with their encoded names?

Thanks,

Comment: you shouldn't really be inserting the encoded text into the DB in the first place, but since you have... don't change the DB. change the user's input. e.g. `htmlspecialchars($user_input)`, then search for that encoded text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a MySQL issue.

The issue is the values you are storing to the database.

If you want to "decode" the HTML entities in a string into the characters they represent, you can use PHP **`html_entity_decode`** function on the value you've scraped from web pages, and then store that value in the database.

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php

---

If you want to store the values in the database as encoded HTML entities, then you could search for those by taking whatever value the user is searching for, and encoding that.  (That probably wasn't clear).

If the user is searching for "`Mr. & Mrs. Smith`", you could encode that using the PHP `htmlentities` function, to return:

```
 Mr. &amp; Mrs. Smith
```

And use that as the search string.

The downside of this approach is that there are multiple ways to encode the same character. And the way that `htmlentities` encodes a string may not match what was done on the webpage. It's possible that some characters may not be encoded at all, etc.

Comment: so, do you think it might be better to scrape them again using `html_entity_decode`? because I would like to update these movies also in my DB (not only to what user are searching)

Comment: @mOna: If you want to update existing values in the database, there's no MySQL builtin function (that I'm aware of) that decodes HTML entities. You could do that in a client application; run a query to retrieve the primary key of the row along with the column you want to change, run the column value through `html_entity_decode`, and then issue an update (set the column to the new value, based on the primary key). That would get you the same result as scraping again.

Comment: Thanks, then do you mean that I should change this part?  `$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT DISTINCT movieName FROM star_film WHERE movieName LIKE :term limit 0, 10');`
            `$stmt->execute(array('term' => '%'.$_GET['term'].'%'));`
            
          `while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {`
             `$return_arr[] =  $row['movieName'];`
           `}`

Comment: I change my code to this: `$return_arr[] = html_entity_decode($row['movieName'], ENT_QUOTES, "ISO-8859-1");`, I could not find Wall.E neither with typing "wall.e" in the textbox, nor with typing "WALL & middot ; E", however, I found it in my search result when I just wrote wall... BUT, I could not find Mr. and Mrs. Smith with any form of typing. Is there something I missed?

Comment: No, if you want to leave the html entities in the database, and you want to search that, you run the user supplied search term **`$_GET['term']`** through the `htmlentities` function.  So for a search term of "**`Mr. & Mrs. Smith`**",  your query would end up being equivalent to `WHERE movieName LIKE '%Mr. &amp; Mrs. Smith%'`. But that approach is not going to work for a **`'wall.e'`** or **`WALL-E`** ... the period and the dash character will *not* be encoded as `&middot;`.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind dealing with each character individually, you can just do this for each:

```
UPDATE movies SET movie_title = REPLACE(movie_title, '&middot;', '·');
```

That is, if you want to replace the HTML entity with the actual character. If you just want to remove the hard-to-type character from current movie titles, simply use '' instead. Do take a backup before you go nuking your database with `REPLACE` though.

You may want to create a new column, e.g. `movie_easytype_title`, where you store a version of the title that's easy to type and match, and still retain the proper full title for display.

You should probably be running `html_entity_decode` on your titles before you input them in the database to avoid storing troublesome HTML entities to begin with.

Comment: So do you think its better to re-crawl them this time by using `html_entity_decode` ?

Comment: Well it depends on how patient you are as far as tracking down each character that needs replacing. I would just reindex, unless it's a massive stash of files and reindexing would take a very long time.

Comment: Sorry, I could not select two answers as correct answers, so I selected the first one as answer and the only thing I could do was Upvote, but anyways thanks a lot for your time and helpful comment :)

Comment: @mOna thanks, what matters is you got your stuff sorted. :)

Answer (score 0):

These solution sounds weird and i also know that it is for url ecoding and decoding. But it works.
while inserting data into database you can use **urlencode()**.
 
And while displaying it you should use **urldecode()**.

Comment: `urlencode()` and `urldecode()` don't deal with HTML entities, they deal with %20 etc. hexed characters. "Decodes any %## encoding in the given string. Plus symbols ('+') are decoded to a space character."

Comment: @MarkusAO  I'm not saying to use only one function. Suppose your data is `H+N` then in database it looks like `H%2BN` and on webpage it's as `H+N`.

Comment: It's only going to look like that if it's URL-encoded to begin with, isn't it. `urldecode` is relevant when the data is received over `GET` variables, otherwise it's quite unlikely that something would be URL-encoded, unless you're harvesting tags' `href/src` attributes or something like that. No harm in `urldecoding` just in case, of course.